# I'm trying to output the already formatted contents of a CSV file into a text channel, but when I do so it's in unordered rows. How can I fix it?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, formatting, discord.py

I'm very new to coding, so this kind of thing is still new to me.

```
import csv
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

f = open('discounts.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

token = '####'
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: #preventing the bot from replying to itself
        return
    
    if message.channel.id == ###:
      if message.content.startswith('.sales'):
          channel = client.get_channel(###)
          msg = 'The latest discounts on Steam are:\n'
          await channel.send(msg)
          for row in csv_f:
              await channel.send(('{:<40}  {:<10}  {:<10}').format(*row).replace('Â',''))
      else:
        await message.delete()

client.run(token)
```

Note that I've replaced the token and channel IDs with '#'.

When ran, this code works as intended, but when I run the '.sales' command in the channel, I get the following from the bot:
[Picture of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO5Jq.png)

When what I should be getting is the following:
[Picture of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IDyB.png)

I'm wondering if this issue is fixable at all, and if so how I would go about doing it, or if there are any other methods of outputting the contents of a CSV file into Discord.

Comment: I did something similar except instead of using the .csv file directly I created a dictionary and used that instead.  Since it looks like your .csv file is local and you'll be manually editing it for new discounts anyway I'd try this.

Comment: Alright I'll try that, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I fixed it by adding backticks around the list, which turns it into a block of code, which means that the lines were ordered successfully:

```
import csv
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

f = open('discounts.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

token = '###'
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user: #preventing the bot from replying to itself
        return
    
    if message.channel.id == ###:
      if message.content.startswith('.sales'):
          channel = client.get_channel(###)
          msg = 'The latest discounts on Steam are:\n'
          await channel.send(msg)
          for row in csv_f:
              await channel.send(('`{:<40}  {:<10}  {:<10}`').format(*row).replace('Â',''))
      else:
        await message.delete()

client.run(token)
```

Hopefully this helps anyone with a similar problem in the future.